# Is it sensible to speak of the parity operator in 4 dimensional Hilbert space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, operators, hilbert-space, parity

So I'm dealing with a system of two qubits, with the hamiltonian given by

$$H =  \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
a & 0 & -b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -b\\
-b & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -b & 0 & -a \end{array} \right] $$

I want to find its eigenvectors. Of course this is a simple mathematical task. But I read somewhere on this website (and I cannot for the life of me find it again of course) that sometimes this can be done very easily by noting whether the hamiltonian commutes with the parity operator. But I have no idea how this "parity operator" is supposed to look in the four dimensional Hilbertspace $H_2 \otimes H_2$. I'm guessing it's the operator that exchanges the two qubits. How would I find its 4x4 matrix representation?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.pa.msu.edu/~mmoore/Lect21_Parity.pdf).

Comment: This seems to pertain to the "space reflection" sort of parity operator. I don't see how to adapt this to my case, where position and momentum don't really exist. I guess in my case, by 'parity operator' I mean something which would exchange the two qubits.

Comment: It certainly does end that way. Treat the highlighted results from pages 3 and 5 as definitions. Part of QM is figuring out what the matrix looks like given that you only know something seemingly abstract - like a parity symmetry.

Comment: I managed to get the form of the matrix by just explicitly demanding that the operator switches 10<->01 while keeping 00 and 11 as they are. I got this $ \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] $ . But I have no idea how to get it abstractly, the way you mention it. Could you give me some hints on how to do that?

Comment: What does it mean for two operators to commute?